# jQuery UI Resizable - wonky resizing if element is placed next to an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I want to offer the page visitor the ability to resize the bar on the left and I tried to use jQuery UI Resizable for this. It works fine when the div next to the #left-bar does not contain an iFrame but if it has an iFrame, the result looks like this:

```css
#main{
    height: 900px;
    width: 1800px;

    background-color: aqua;

    display: flex;
}

#left-bar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;

    background-color: blue;

    outline: medium solid red;

    margin-right: 1px;

    display: inline-block;
}

#topic-window{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: navy;

    outline: medium solid red;

    display: inline-block;
}

#docWindow{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position:relative;

  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#left-bar").resizable({ 
                direction: 'right' 
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left-bar"></div>
        <div id="topic-window">
            <iframe id="docWindow"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it works when there is no iFrame in the #topic-window div:

```css
#main{
    height: 900px;
    width: 1800px;

    background-color: aqua;

    display: flex;
}

#left-bar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;

    background-color: blue;

    outline: medium solid red;

    margin-right: 1px;

    display: inline-block;
}

#topic-window{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: navy;

    outline: medium solid red;

    display: inline-block;
}

#docWindow{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position:relative;

  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#left-bar").resizable({ 
                direction: 'right' 
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left-bar"></div>
        <div id="topic-window">
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see, it's pretty smooth when there is no iFrame. That's the performance I want.
I am new with jQuery so I can't figure a way around this, can anyone point me in a direction to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the effect of the iframe window "swallowing" the mouse move events, which the resize plugin itself needs to determine which way you are moving the divider.

You should be able to counter-act this, by setting `pointer-events: none` for all elements inside the panels, when resizing starts - and removing it again, when it stops.

```css
#main{
    height: 900px;
    width: 1800px;

    background-color: aqua;

    display: flex;
}

#left-bar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;

    background-color: blue;

    outline: medium solid red;

    margin-right: 1px;

    display: inline-block;
}

#topic-window{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: navy;

    outline: medium solid red;

    display: inline-block;
}

#docWindow{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position:relative;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.ignore-pointer-events > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#left-bar").resizable({ 
                direction: 'right',
                start: function() {
                  $('#left-bar, #topic-window').addClass('ignore-pointer-events');
                },
                stop: function() {
                  $('#left-bar, #topic-window').removeClass('ignore-pointer-events');
                },               
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left-bar"></div>
        <div id="topic-window">
            <iframe id="docWindow"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much sense that an iFrame would swallow mouse move events intended for resizing. There's still two issues with this method that brings down the quality though, I'm not sure if they're worth opening another question for. First is that the cursor is always faster than the resize growth, as you've probably noticed. Second is that when visitor tries to resize again after the first resize, the right border seems to snap to a fixed location before it starts moving. Should I open a new question for these?

Comment: The first issue already existed in the iframe-less example you posted, so I think that is completely independent of this. And the second one is probably due to a typo, my code did not correctly remove the `ignore-pointer-events` from the left panel again, that should be fixed now.

Comment: You're right, it's independent. But I've managed to fix it by playing with the flex properties and the display properties of the elements a little bit. I am posting the final product now for all who are curious.

Answer (score 1):

With help from CBroe and some additions from myself, I got the result that works just the way I wanted.

Here is the snippet for all who are interested:

```css
#main{
    height: 900px;
    width: 1800px;

    background-color: aqua;

    display: flex;
}

#left-bar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;

    background-color: blue;

    outline: medium solid red;

    margin-right: 1px;

    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#topic-window{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: navy;

    outline: medium solid red;

    flex: 1 1 0;
}

#docWindow{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position:relative;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.ignore-pointer-events > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#left-bar").resizable({ 
                direction: 'right',
                resizeWidthFrom: 'left',
                start: function() {
                  $('#left-bar, #topic-window').addClass('ignore-pointer-events');
                },
                stop: function() {
                  $('#left-bar, #topic-window').removeClass('ignore-pointer-events');
                },               
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left-bar"></div>
        <div id="topic-window">
            <iframe id="docWindow"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).